# Remove index.php and redirect to https sudomain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

**.htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
Options -Indexes
```

I want to remove `index.php` from URL and also when someone enters `test.xyz.com` in the address bar it should redirect to `https://test.xyz.com`.

I tried some codes as below by commenting the above code and then the problem was that when I enter `test.xyz.com` it's automatically redirecting to `https://test.xyz.com` but when I go to some other link like `https://test.xyz.com/user/list` its showing error.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

So I need a better .htaccess file which will remove `index.php` as well as redirect to `https` for all URLs in my subdomain.

> **NOTE:** Need combined version of both the above `.htaccess` code.

Comment: url cannot be reached error. I know the problem when I'm using the second `.htaccess` code is that I'm not removing `index.php` from url that means if I got to `https://test.xyz.com/index.php/user/list` it will work fine

Comment: The first one is the only code I used initially. That is to remove `index.php`. After that I commented all those code and tried the second one.

Comment: Yes of course..

Comment: But `http://test.xyz.com/user/list` didn't work. i.e  if we remove `https`

Comment: Yes just with first block rule `https://test.xyz.com/user/list` url works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this code in your site root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes   
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache or test in a new browser.

Comment: Perfect !!. Works fine. Thank you so much.